# How does distribution within a target group with an ELB work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I am trying to understand how traffic is routed within a target group. My current understanding is, I create a target group that may contain multiple servers, and can have an application load balancer send traffic to this target group based on rules that I configure. But once traffic is sent to a target group, then what happens? How is it determined which instance serves the request?

Answer (score 2):

The traffic that is sent to your target group is balanced through all your instances that are part of the target group. This is done by the Elastic Load Balancer. For example, under the hood, the ELB might keep some reference about the number of requests it has sent during the last minute to an instance and if the request rate "threshold" is exceeded, the traffic goes to the other instances in the target group.

Additionally, if you want to stick to one instance for the entire session, you can enable Sticky Sessions on the ALB.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. For the point about sticky sessions, what if you are using an application load balancer? I ask about this case because I just learned that sticky sessions for an application load balancer are at the target group level.

Comment: The sticky sessions are enabled at the target group level, which means that the traffic routed to that target group will stick to a specific instance until some duration or some cookie is present in the request. The traffic is routed to the same instance based on the cookie that comes with the request (this is what happens on the background).